# Failed to initialize BattlEye Service in Fortnite

Tags: technical-issues, fortnite-battle-royale, fortnite-save-the-world

I installed Fortnite, and then Windows Update tells me it needs to restart to install Windows 10 Build 17083, so I restart my PC and the update successfully installs, but the thing is - when I run Fortnite for the first time, this message pops up:

> Failed to initialize BattlEye Service: Driver Load Error (193).

[image: Failed to initialize BattlEye Service: Driver Load Error (193).]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by disabling virtualization in the BIOS. Not a proper fix though, I need virtualization for my Windows Server hosts in Hyper-V.

Comment: That's strange, I have it enabled on my machine and it runs just fine. Maybe it was just the restart?

Comment: @Codingale maybe it's because I enabled Hyper-V?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/436520/discussions/0/135508031953435830/) on Steam from a developer who gave these ideas of solving the issue.

> Hello,
>
> Please try the following Steps, if you are experiencing issues with Battleye.
>
> - Make sure that BEService.exe in your BE Service directory (usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Line of Sight\Binaries\Win32\BattlEye`) is not blocked by your firewall in any way.
> - Ensure that there is no d3d9.dll, dxgi.dll or dsound.dll file in your game directory. If there is one please remove/rename it.
> - Ensure that you have a legitimate copy of Windows. Pirated copies might no longer be supported by the latest BE version.
> - Check if your game directory’s file permissions are broken by doing the following: Right-click on your game directory (in Windows Explorer), select “Properties” and go to the “Security” tab. In the group/user list select the “SYSTEM” entry and check if it has full access. Otherwise click “Edit…” and grant the “SYSTEM” user full access.
> - Your system’s root certificates might be broken/corrupted. To fix them download and install the following update from Microsoft: [support.microsoft.com/kb/2813430](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2813430).
> - Check your system files for corruptions and possibly repair them by following these guides: [support.microsoft.com/kb/929833](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) and [support.microsoft.com/kb/947821](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821).
> - Scan your system with up-to-date anti-virus and anti-malware software. Malware that modifies system or game files can cause such issues when BE is enabled.
> - Googling the name of the blocked file can help find out what is actually behind it. Sometimes BE might block malware/adware/PUP files, which can cause problems such as being unable to find or connect to servers in-game. We recommend Malwarebytes Anti-Malware for removing such software from your system.
> - Ensure that you don’t use any tweaked/custom versions of system files (including DirectX).
> - Reinstall DirectX, see the following page for details: [support.microsoft.com/kb/179113](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/179113).
>
> If these steps do not help, please also visit the Battleeye FAQ, which can be found [here](https://www.battleye.com).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved it by going to the directory where the game is installed:

```
FortniteGame/Binaries/Win64/BattlEye
```

There you will find:

```
Install_BattlEye.exe
```

Run it, and BattlEye should reinstall. That solved it for me.